# Where should writeable SQLite db be stored?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I want to create an SQLite database in which data is stored that the user entered in my app.

Reading [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65137/where-should-i-store-users-app-data-files) post, I opted for

```
string dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

When I try to write to this folder, I get the following error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/data/user/0/MyApp.Android/files' is denied.
```

Is it "normal" that this folder is not writable?
I tried it on a clean Android device which developers functionality enabled.

If this folder should not be used, which one should I use instead?

Thank you very much!

Edit: I'm not sure yet if my problem is related to another post as I seem to have problems writing to ANY directory on the device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/ship-an-application-with-a-database)

Comment: do you have the correct permissions set in your manifest?

Comment: @Jason I have requested all possible rights just to make sure. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The path should be `/data/data/package_name/databases`.

Comment: [Here](http://oacnlc1wt.bkt.clouddn.com/Capture.PNG) is the databases path, you can use ADM to check it.